# I set background color on listview items (on click) but the listview refreshes only when i scroll the listview. Anyone solution? Here is my code

Tags: android

From my adapter class which extends `SimpleAdapter`

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    HashMap<String,String> h=(HashMap<String,String>) this.getItem(position);

    if(h.containsKey("isSelected")&& h.containsValue("true"))
    {
        if(convertView!=null){
            convertView.setSelected(true);
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
    else if(convertView!=null)
    {
        if(convertView!=null){
            convertView.setSelected(false);
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
}
```

---

From my Activity as below

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {
    // getting listitem index

    HashMap<String, String> s = songsList.get(position);
    if(!mainSongs.contains(s))
    {
        mainSongs.add(s);
        ((HashMap<String,String>)adapter.getItem(position)).put("isSelected","true");
        lv.refreshDrawableState();
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Can you describe more about what you want?

Comment: i want to change background color of items in listview that are clicked immediately. It changes the color , but after i touch and scroll the listview.

Answer (score 0):

i think you set background color not cause getView。